# reasons behind decreasing of "last value" of a SEQUENCE automatically in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment, sequences

I am using a "sequence" with start value = 1 and increment = 1 and suppose i insert 10 elements in the table then "last_value" goes to 10. now if i delete 10th element then "last_value" still points to 10. now my question is, is there any possibility that value of "last_value" may decrease to 9 by killing postgres or by taking dump and then again restoring the database (or any other case).

In my case it happened (i don't know how).please provide possible reasons for this.

Comment: No, the sequence will never "decrease" itself (unless it wraps around, but that is very unlikely with just 10 values). Most probably someone manually inserted that value into the table. Just because a column is populated by a sequence doesn't mean you can't overwrite that.

Comment: This only happens when you want it to happen when you set a new value for the next round. It can also happen when you have created a sequence that starts all over again when the maximum value has been reached. But it's always your choice, it can't happen by accident.

Comment: ok. i found out the reason. if you take the dump and then restore the db(by deleting the previous one) and start the server again then issue gets created.

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 cases, when a sequence is "decreased":

- Sequence reached its `MAXVALUE` and is reset to `MINVALUE` . This can be controled with `[ NO ] CYCLE` in `CREATE SEQUENCE`
- Sequence is explicitly reset with `setval()`

There are no other ways to get the same value from a sequence 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of a sequence.

```
SELECT setval('public.sequence_name', 9, true);
```

However, if you need the values to be contiguous, I'm not sure that a sequence is the most appropriate way to go about that.  Perhaps using `rank()`?

Comment: i want the possible reasons when value of "last_value" decreases automatically.

Comment: The only way I can think that it would decrease that way would be for the database to be rolled back to a previous state or to be set explicitly.  Are you using any kind of replication like slony?

Comment: Not even a rollback will decrease the number, see the manual: Important: Because sequences are non-transactional, changes made by setval are not undone if the transaction rolls back.